# Angular directive works on an element in the first page but stop working after navigation (probably a scope issue)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

the directive code

```
directive('stFloatBar', function($log,$window){
        return{
            restrict:'A',
            replace:true,
            transclude:true,
            templateUrl:'partials/directives/topfloatnav.html',
//            scope: {target:'=stFloatBar'},
            link:function(scope,element,attrs){
                var oldvalue;
                $window = angular.element($window);

                        $window.on('scroll',function(ev){
                            scrollShow(attrs.stFloatBar);
                        });

               var back = element.find('.scrollBack');

                var scrollBack = function(){
                  scope.$apply($window[0].scrollTo(0));
                };

                back.bind('click',scrollBack);
                scope.shower = false;
                var scrollShow = function(dest){
                    var trigger =$(dest)[0].getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
                    var triggerPoint = attrs.stFloatTriggerpoint;

                    if (trigger < triggerPoint && scope.shower==false){
                        scope.shower = true;
                        scope.$apply(attrs.stSetfloat);
                    }
                    if(trigger > triggerPoint && scope.shower==true){
                        scope.shower=false
                        scope.$apply(attrs.stSetfloat);
                    }
                };
        }
        };
    })
```

and the html calling the directive:

```
<div st-float-bar="div.userTop" st-float-triggerpoint="80" st-setfloat="setShowFloat()" ng-show="showFloat"></div>
```

basically the directives need to calculate some data from the Html target element (Its bottom)

this work on the first page showing and hiding the floating bar correctly and listening to the scrolling event(doesn't matter if I start with page1 or page2) But when I navigate to the second page I get a console error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getBoundingClientRect' of undefined
```

So I guess the problem is that the binding doesn't change, But I can figure how?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could it be just that the `template` has not been rendered when `$(dest)[0]` tries to access it while `scroll` event is being fired? In that case, just testing whether `$(dest)` found any elements at all should be enough.

Comment: @musically_ut - thanks! How would I do that

Comment: @musically_ut DONE! solved the problem, you can write this as an answer so I can reward you the points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In angular, the template is not rendered in the same `$digest` loop which runs the `link` function. Hence, the template of the element is *empty* on page change while the window's `scroll` event fires irrespective.

Solution is to check whether `$(dest)` found any elements at all and if it didn't, then not to take any action at all.

**Sidenote**: It is always best if a [directive cleans up after itself](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-custom-directives_demo_creating-a-directive-that-manipulates-the-dom) by **unregistering all event listeners** when `$destroy` event is called on the `$scope`. Otherwise, the application runs a risk of running into a memory leak.

Comment: how do I do that? register the destroy?

Comment: The `demo` on the link has an example of how to do that: `scope.$on('$destroy', function () { /* unregister listeners */ })`.